# How to Databind a Repeater to a XML file?

Tags: xml, vb.net, winforms, data-binding, repeater

I am trying to create a repeater that has two text boxes and a label. I need to repeat this row 25 times. I'm trying to bind the repeater to a xml empty table to produce what I need. I was able to do this on a web application but not on this windows form. Code show below. When I tried to Bind the data for the DataRepeater1.Databind. The DataBind method does not shows. Im using .net 4  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Form1.vb

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim dataset As DataSet = New DataSet
    dataset.ReadXml("EmptyTable.xmls")
    DataRepeater1.DataSource = dataset.Tables

End Sub
```

EmptyTable.xml

```
<Employeed>
 <cd>
  <ID>     </ID>
  <Name>    </Name>
  <ACode>    </ACode>
 </cd>
.
.
.
.
  repeat same row 25 times
  <Employeed>
```

Comment: try: `DataRepeater1.DataSource = dataset.Tables(0)`

Comment: Spell check your file name - `EmptyTable.xmls`

Comment: @OneFineDay thanks for taking the time of checking my answer. I changed my typo and try DataReapeater1.DataSource = dataset.Tables(0) but It did not work. DO you have any other ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Are you still calling `Databind`? You should be. Debug it and check the Dataset to see if it filled.

Comment: That is the problem that I have that it does not recognize Databind(). 'Databind is not a member of Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPack.DataRepeater'

Comment: Well then do some research on your control. Did you check to see if your dataset was filling?

Comment: @OneFineDay yes I checked and it was empty. I just double check my question and I realized that I mistyped something. What I'm trying to do is for a windows form application. Thanks for the help